# How can I reference field values in another field on the same entity form?

Tags: entities, 8

Example content type that has two fields:

1. Text field `field_value` with multiple values allowed.
2. A custom field `field_error` (defined with field type plugin) that contains few text "properties" (similar to `alt` and `title` properties of an image field). The properties are: `reference` and `message`. This is also multi-value field.

I want to achieve similar behaviour to the `machine_name` form element which takes it's default value by transliterating other field value. In my case this would be the `field_error`'s field property `reference` to actually reference one of the values of the field `field_value`.

Is there a module that would help me to achieve that?

If not then I don't mind coding it myself. This challenge could be split into two separate issues:

1. `field_error` configuration that would require admin to select a target field for reference. **Question**: can I somehow access other field names from the content entity type for which the field is being configured? `storageSettingsForm()` gets only `$form` array and `$form_state` arguments.
2. Client side JavaScript that would use that information to dynamically build select options for `reference` property of field `field_value`. **Question**: is there Drupal way for accessing field values inside JS or do I have to code everything from scratch?

Comment: Why not just copy what the core machine name field does?

Comment: Core's `machine_name` is not a real field - it's only a form element. It's attached JavaScript can probably help resolving 2nd issue, but there is still a matter of defining the relationship when field is configured.

Comment: is it always a 1-1 relationship between field_value and field_error?

Comment: @squall3d Nope, multiple `field_error` may reference one `field_value`.